# Bidirectional binding for flex ComboBox?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a collection that I want to bind as data input for a `ComboBox`:

```
private static var LOGOS:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
 {index:0, label=logo1}, 
 {index:1, label=logo2}
]);

<s:ComboBox selectedItem="@{model.labelIndex}" labelField="@label" dataProvider="{LOGOS}" />
```

Now, when selecting an item, the binding should send the associated `index` property of the objext to the model and update `labelIndex`.
Of course it does not work as above, because `labelIndex` is of different datatype than the `ArrayCollection`.

```
[Bindable]
private var model:MyModel;

[Bindable]
class MyModel {
   public var:Number labelIndex;
}
```

Question: how can I map the array element to the model and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for will require some scripting, binding isn't smart enough to figure out how to handle this on its own.

You can use the `BindingUtils` class to define the bindings, and use the `chain` argument of the `bindProperty` method to modify how values are being looked up.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html

For the `combo.selectedItem` to `model.labelIndex` binding, you can specify the chain as an array, where the elements define the path where to look for the value:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(model, 'labelIndex', combo, ['selectedItem', 'index']);
```

This will bind to the `selectedItem` property, and pass the value of the items `index` property.

The other way around is a little more tricky and will require using a getter function which grabs the object from the datasource, based on the `labelIndex` value:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(combo, 'selectedItem', model, {
    name: 'labelIndex',
    getter: function(host:MyModel):Object
    {
        return LOGOS.source.filter(function(item:Object, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
        {
            return item.index === host.labelIndex;
        })[0];
    }
});
```

This will bind to the `labelIndex` property, and the `getter` function will be invoked when the property changes. The function will filter the datasource based on the models changed `labelIndex` property value, and return the source object with the matching `index` property value, which will finally be set for the combobox `selectedItem` property.

Your combobox definition will of course need an `id` in order to be targetable via script

```
<s:ComboBox id="combo" dataProvider="{LOGOS}" />
```

Note that there's no need forthe the `@` in the `labelField` property, this is only used with XML datasources where you need to target an attribute. However, actually you don't need to specify this at all, since `label` is the default value of the `labelField` property.

Comment: But what if the `index` is not a sequence, like having `1,2,5,17`? Would your code still work with that?

Comment: @membersound I misunderstood your question, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Anyways this is really complicated code for just getting a simple checkbox with data fed. I mean, it's a common requirement for a UI framework to have some kind of data object as datasource for a checkbox, where the choices should only display partial properties of the object, and the link to the model should also just use partial properties (in my case: the index of an element, which will be persisted to DB so the user settings can be restored on login). Isn't there any simpler way of doing this?

Comment: @membersound To me this already is rather simple, given that Flex is not that flexible after all. Could it be that I got you wrong again? You want the selected item in the combobox to change when the `labelIndex` property changes, right? Or do you want to change the `index` property of the currently selected item when the models `labelIndex` property changes?

Comment: Primary, I want the combobox to be bound to the `ArrayCollection` in my initial question. The default selection should be set by binding the current selection of the combobox to a `modelDTO` which has a `index:Number` property from DB. Any changes on the combobox (which displays only the `label property`) should trigger an update to the model `index` property.

Comment: @membersound Ok, so I got you right then. AFAICT this is as simple as it gets, what are looking for isn't possible without custom scripting, Flex' databinding capabilities are rather limited.

Comment: Where would I initiialized the `BindingUtils` code best? In a static code segment in mxml files?